# Query selector with puppeteer returns empty array

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've got a short scraper written to pull some titles from a page using Puppeteer. While I can scrape individual elements, like a lone h2, trying to scrape and return an array of items hasn't been successful.

Mainly I've tried to make sure my query selector is even working, I can run `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.landscape h3.title')).map(partner => partner.textContent)` in my Chrome dev tools and get the array I'm looking for, but running it in my script returns an empty array `[]`. As stated before, using just a lone querySelect('h2') seems to work fine.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/partners/find-a-partner');

  const titlesArray = await page.evaluate(
    () => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.landscape h3.title')).map(partner => partner.textContent)
  );


  console.log(titlesArray);


  await browser.close();
})();
```

No error messages seem to produce, just a console log of an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the page first loads, it shows a "Loading" text and redirects/loads data from there.

You have to wait for the element to be present in the DOM. Here is what the code might look,

```
await page.goto('https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/partners/find-a-partner');
await page.waitForSelector('div.landscape h3.title'); // <-- add this line //updated from page.waitFor that is getting deprecated in 2020
```

Comment: This was exactly it! Alternatively, I also used `await page.waitFor(2000); ` to wait for the page to load after 2 seconds, before moving onto creating my array. Fantastic and thank you!